# Ошибка при загрузке php

Tags: php

Код:

```
    <?php

   if($_FILES["filename"]["size"] > 1024*25*1024)
   {
     $message = 'Размер файла превышает 25 мегабайт, к сожалению, загружать файлы более 25 мегабайт могут только пользователи тарифа premium';
     exit;
   }
   // Проверяем загружен ли файл
   if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]))
   {
     // Если файл загружен успешно, перемещаем его
     // из временной директории в конечную
     move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "share/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]);

     $message = 'Файл загружен успешшно!';
   } else {
      $message = 'Ошибка загрузки файла, попробуйте еще раз';
   }

?>
```

Форма с `enctype = 'multipart/form-data'`

в `php.ini` у меня

```
upload_max_file_size: 25M
 Max_post_data = 25M 
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
```

В чем проблема? Почему пишет "Ошибка загрузки файла, попробуйте еще раз"?

Comment: Какой атрибут name у `<inpy type="file" />` ?

Comment: <form action = "upload.php" method = "post" enctype = 'multipart/form-data'>
        Выберите файл:
        <input type="file" name="file" /><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" class="button red" value="Отправить файл на сервер" />
        </form>

Comment: И вар дамп $files: array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(17) "1326889022150.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/php6KJAko" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(35993) } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@ХэшКод](/users/1/%D1%85%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4), в вопросе аномалия, форма ответа заэскейпена зачем-то.

[[@butteff](/users/5609/butteff)](/users/5609/butteff), исправьте либо в коде `$_FILES["filename"]` на `$_FILES["file"]`, либо в форме `<input type="file" name="filename" />`